# How to call a large python script in C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, unix, ubuntu

I am trying to take aspects of two different scripts and use them in a single C++ program (using Ubuntu). The problem I have is that one of the scripts is written in C++ and the other is written in python. I have been trying to accomplish this using the Python.h library, but (being fairly new to programming), I cannot find any resources that would allow me to open the python file in C++. Does anyone have any suggestions?

As an example, I want to do something like the following:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>
//include other stuff

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //open python script here 
    //use result from python script here
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Lookup `system` OR `popen` system calls. `man 2 system` OR `man 2 popen`

Comment: Just for future reference, C++ is not considered a script because it is a compiled language. Also, large Python scripts are called/started just the same way as small ones. The other advice you have received is good - `system()` if you are not interested in gathering the output of your Python script and `popen()` if you are.

Answer (score 0):

You should use popen, it pipes stdin/stdout of child process to returned file handle. Now what you can do is

```
File* in = popen("python script_name.py", "r");
```

Now you can use this `FILE*` to read the output of your python script.

Than you can use `fscanf(in, buffer_size, buffer)` of `fgets(buffer, buffer_size, in)` to read from file. Finally after reading from file don't forget to call `pclose(in)`.